# Export an object with Spring JMX annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jmx

I'm trying to export some information with Spring JMX annotation driven (I have no xml :D). I have achieved to export Strings and Integer types but I haven't been able to export any object of a class I created.

This is my @Configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport
@ComponentScan({"my.packages"})
public class AppManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppManager.class);
        context.refresh();


        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmxExporter")
    public Exporter jmxExporter() {
        return new Exporter();
    }
}
```

This is some class I have with some attributes I want to get.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private int param1;
    private int param2;
    private int param3;

    public MyClass() {
        // calculate all params
    }

    public int getParam1() {
        return this.param1;
    }

    public int getParam2() {
        return this.param2;
    }

    public int getParam3() {
        return this.param3;
    }

}
```

This is the class that exports it's attributes.

```
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;

@ManagedResource(objectName = "my.packages:type=JMX,name=Exporter")
public class Exporter {

    @ManagedAttribute
    public String getString() { //This works!
        return "Test string";
    }

    @ManagedAttribute
    public MyClass getMyClass() { //This does not work
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

I need to create MyClass object every time because it has some real-time information that I can't export separately.

In JConsole the value of attribute is "Unavailable".

I'm pretty new to JMX and obviously missing something.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by returning CompositeData.

```
@ManagedAttribute
public CompositeData getMyClass() { 
    return createCompositeDataForMyClass();
}
```

I built a CompositeDataSupport for that and it worked.

```
return new CompositeDataSupport(compositeType, itemNames, itemValues);
```

Where compositeType is a CompositeType, itemNames is a String[] and itemValues is an Object[].

The CompositeType can be built with something like this

```
new CompositeType(typeName, typeDescription, itemNames, itemDescriptions, itemTypes);
```

typeName, typeDescription are Strings. itemNames and itemDescriptions are String[]. itemTypes is an OpenType[]. SimpleType and CompositeType can be used to build OpenType.

All this objects must be imported with

```
import javax.management.openmbean.*;
```